# .encode with errors='replace' is not replacing all errors

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have "solved" the problem I'm getting here by simply replacing errors both at encode and decode stages, but I'd rather know the actual reason why it's happening.

When I use `.encode()` with certain characters in ANSI, I don't get the replacement of all special characters with question marks/replacement character as I desired. It's necessary that I use ANSI because that's what the program I'm exporting to requires, but in many other encodings I do get the desired behaviour.

`'βßγ'.encode(encoding = 'ANSI', errors = 'replace')`

Output:
`b'\xdf\xdf?'`

So, 'γ' and other Greek letters are encoded as '?' as I wished, but 'β' comes up as '\xdf', same as the German 'ß', and instead of being replaced gets an escape code. I've learned that in some character sets, 'β' and 'ß' are given the same character to save space. So neither 'β' nor 'ß' gets replaced with '?'.

So I've "encoded" it, but then when I try .decode later, I still have to use `.decode(errors = 'replace')`. Could somebody explain why I have to replace errors twice? Thank you!

Comment: Take note that this works for me as desired when using the ASCII encoding (ANSI is not available on my system). Are you sure you need ANSI, not ASCII?

Comment: tried `b'\xdf\xdf?'.decode(encoding = 'ANSI')` and i get `'ßß?'`. Which i believe what you are expecting(?) You don't need `errors = replace ` here

Comment: For some reason, my software is documented as requiring ANSI. But thank you - I hadn't specified decode(encoding = 'ANSI'), which I should have done. I guess it flicks my compulsive switch a little to see 'ß' come out of the other end when I wanted a Greek letter, more than '?' does for some reason, but I guess that is a limitation of ANSI. Thank you.